# Can't import packages from jsqlparser library

Tags: java, netbeans, sql-parser

I added the jar jsqlparser-0.7.0 to my Netbeans IDE (right clic on  libraries / Add Jar file) but i still can't use its packages. what could be the reason . The library is created on 2011 it could be it is not supported by JDK7?

[image]

Comment: try to refresh your code

Comment: I alrady did that ; I closed netbeans and reopened it too

Comment: To get a good answer please provide more details about what is not working.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert , i posted a picture , the IDE can't detect the lib as its not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JAR file "jsqlparser-0.7.0.jar" is not a regular Java library. It is a simple zipped file containing several artifacts: a source and a documentation directory, some testfiles, and - what you need - another JAR called "jsqlparser.jar" in a lib directory.

This JAR is the "real library" that you must add to your project. Additionally, all packages inside this library start with "net.sf.jsqlparser".

Comment: And once you've got the library in per above, you'll probably want to shotgun some imports.  I've pasted all of the 0.7 ones here for convenience:

`
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.operators.arithmetic.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.operators.conditional.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.operators.relational.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.schema.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.*;
  import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.create.table.*;
`

Comment: And:
`
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.delete.*;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.drop.*;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.insert.*;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.replace.*;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.*;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.truncate.*;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.update.*;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.util.deparser.*;`

Answer (score -1):

Just put this:

```
import jsqlparser.*;
```

Comment: package jsqlparser doesn't exist